# Multithreaded MVC design in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, model-view-controller

I have been wroking on a design to implement a multi threaded Model-View-Controller in C++ and I stumble upon difficulties. I have some requirements I am trying to enforce:

1. Make the design as simple as possible to use. Typically, when I modify the content of my model, I want the view to automatically update the display ; I don't want the programmer to have to explicitly notify the view. Ideally, an update to the model should be as simple as:

   Model model;
   [...]
   model.set_value() = 12; // Considering value is a integer here, but could be any data type

   This would trigger an update of the view
2. Multiple threads can update the model concurrently.
3. Possility to discriminate read and write calls to the model so read calls don't trigger a view update.
4. As lightning fast as possible, so the use of Producer/Consumer queue,   generating a lot of small memory allocation for each message is an option I'd like to avoid.

My solution however does not satisfy those requirements and, although it kind of work, I am not entirely satisfied ; That is why I'm turning to the community to see if a successful implementation exists out there.

My solution first rely on the observer/observable pattern. A view is an observer and the model is an observable. Then I use macros to declare data within the model such as:

```
class Observer {
  void register(Callback);
  void unregister(Callback);
  void notify(Callback);
}
```

Callback being a `std::function<void()>`

```
class Type {
  // Some data Type
}

class Model : public Observer {
  // Type can be a class or just some fundamental C++ types such as int...
  DECLARE(Model, field, Type)
}

// [...]
// Then, somewhere in the code...
Model model;
model.set_field().update() = some_value;
```

`DECLARE` is a macro that will create get_ and set_ accessors. The set_
accessor will return an object, let's call it Update, which will contain a
reference to the model member. Here update is a method of this object which
returns a reference to field which can then be updated. Upon desctruction will
call the notify callback:

```
// What is the name of that design pattern ?
<template T>
class Update {
public:
  Update(T &t, Callback callback) : m_t(t), m_callback(callback)
  {}
  ~Update() { m_callback(); }
  T& update() { return m_t; }

private:
  T &m_t;
  Callback m_callback;
}
```

This is well and good but as I have several threads updating the model, I will need some synchronization device somewhere. A mutex in the Update object ?

Moreover, several thread running View code will end up messing my screen (rendered with ncurses) so I also need a synchronization on the view side. I
though of creating a thread that would run the View code and which would receive "messages" from the model upon update but I am afraid this would have a significative impact on performance.
I don't want to implement a "digest loop" à la Angular either which would reduce the reactivity of my UI (which is a terminal app driven mainly by the keyboard).

Anyway, did you evenr this kind of design? Do you have some pointers to
successful implementation? Do you have some hints?

Comment: Don't run the view with multiple threads.  That's *over-engineered* and it won't work, or at the very least you'll get stuck in some very deep mud.  You won't gain any performance doing it.

Comment: the use of std::move in your template code is bad.
keep it as a reference.
not as an rvalue.